# Is there a "friendly" way to identify myself when enabling bluetooth discovery on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I wish to scan the discoverable devices nearby my handset via bluetooth. How do I know which one is the desirable candidate I wish to connect WITHOUT pairing first? I know that there is a physical address, name and UUID that can be used to identify the device.

However, physical address and UUID are random meaningless strings that cannot carry extra information. Device name can be readable which is a good thing, but how do I change it? Can I change the bluetooth name without changing the device name? Or is there other ways to do it without pairing?

For example, by UDP one can broadcast "I am Winston Smith" and everybody will be able to hear it and knows it is Winston Smith. Is there something similar in bluetooth?